# addEventListener(object[i]) in for loop gives me one object not multiple

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, textfield, addeventlistener

i am making a leaderboard for a game. this leaderboard gets its scores from the an array. but when i add the eventListener i get only one of the object from the array.
this is mine object array:

```
[{gamenr:1,naam:"wilbert", score:60},{gamenr:1,naam:"joost", score:20},
{gamenr:2,naam:"harry", score:50},{gamenr:2,naam:"john", score:10},
{gamenr:3,naam:"carl", score:30},{gamenr:3,naam:"dj", score:16}]
```

code:

```
public function toonHighscoreArray():Array {
highScoreTabel.sortOn(["score"], [Array.NUMERIC]).reverse();//get highest score on top
var returnArray:Array = new Array();
for ( var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    var scores:TextField = new TextField();
    scores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){toon2deSpeler(highScoreTabel[i])});

    scores.y = (i * 50) - 50;
    scores.height = 50;
    scores.text = "" + (i + 1) + ".\t" + highScoreTabel[i].naam + " met " + highScoreTabel[i].score + " punten.";
    scores.autoSize = "left";

    returnArray.push(scores);
}
return returnArray;
}

private function toon2deSpeler(score:Object) {
    trace(score.naam);
}
```

i want the function toon2deSpeler to trace wilbert when i click the textfield where wilbert is in the textfield is clicked and harry when harry's textfield is clicked

but it gives me joost when i click wilbert but also when i click harry or joost ect.

how do i get the right object as parameter in toon2deSpeler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions run in the scope in which they were created ([See this page on Function scope](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f54.html)), so your inline listener:

```
function(e:MouseEvent){toon2deSpeler(highScoreTabel[i])}
```

is using the `i` from `toonHighscoreArray()`, not it's "own" copy of `i`. Given your code there though, you would be getting a null object reference instead of "joost", as you're trying to access highScoreTabel[6].

I would really recommend extending `TextField` and creating objects with the properties from `highScoreTabel`, then using Barış Uşaklı's method. However, it is possible to create each listener function in its own scope like this:

```
function getScoreClickListener(scoreID:uint):Function {
    return function(e:MouseEvent){toon2deSpeler(highScoreTabel[scoreID])}
}
```

Then use that when adding your even listener:

```
scores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getScoreClickListener(i));
```

This makes it difficult to remove the event listeners later though, so you'd need to keep track of them separately.

Answer (score 3):

Closures inside loops are not going to work as you expect, once the event handler is called it will use the last value of `i`.

Change your for loop to this :

```
for ( var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    var scores:TextField = new TextField();
    addScoreListener(scores, i);

    scores.y = (i * 50) - 50;
    scores.height = 50;
    scores.text = "" + (i + 1) + ".\t" + highScoreTabel[i].naam + " met " + highScoreTabel[i].score + " punten.";
    scores.autoSize = "left";

    returnArray.push(scores);
}

private function addScoreListener(score:TextField, index:int):void
{
   scores.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void{
       toon2deSpeler(highScoreTabel[index]);
   });
}
```

Comment: that gives me the textfield, but i want the object

Comment: updated my answer, see @David's answer too, you should really extend TextField and make your own class and put the properties you store in those objects in to that class.